# Android: Execute method at a fixed time

Tags: java, android, eclipse, if-statement, dynamic

I'm creating an app that has to play sounds over a background music at a fixed time. So far i managed to overlap the sounds with no problems and set a timer, but now i want one sound start playing at exactly 10 seconds after the timer starts counting.
I'm trying to create an "if" that checks the value of my timer textview and executes the "start playing" command, but i don't know how to make it to dynamically check the value. Is this the right approach to my problem? or should i use another method?

This is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnPreparedListener  {


private MediaPlayer media1 = new MediaPlayer();
private MediaPlayer media2 = new MediaPlayer();
private TextView timerValue;
private long  startTime = 0L;
private Handler customHandler = new Handler(); 

long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);

     playaudio();
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

protected void playaudio() 
{
    try {
        media1.setDataSource("http://tauruszone.sytes.net/uno.mp3");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    media1.prepareAsync();
    media1.setOnPreparedListener(this);

try {
    media2.setDataSource("http://tauruszone.sytes.net/dos.mp3");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
media2.prepareAsync();
media2.setOnPreparedListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
    startplaying();
}


private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", secs));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
};

protected void  startplaying() 
{
    media1.start();
// This is the code im struggling with:
    if(timerValue.getText().toString().equals(00:10)){
       media2.start();
       }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: But does AlarmManager work for counting after a method was iniciated? I was under the impression that it worked for calling events at absolute time, like 9 PM or so. Could you give me an example of how it would apply to my problem? Thanks.

Comment: You can start the `AlarmManager` in your method itself

Comment: A "Timer" can do that job too. myTimer = new Timer(); and then myTimer.schedule (yourTaskHere, 10000); 10000 being 10s in miliseconds.

Comment: Can i set several timers with this method? Like, one goes off at ten seconds, other at 30, other at 2 minutes and so on and so on?

Comment: Also, the new timer makes my textview timer restart. How can i avoid this?